# libevent support HTTP redirect

Tags: http, libevent

I am trying to use libevent to emulate multiple HTTP clients.  The following code snippet works but unfortunately it doesn't seem to support HTTP rediect (301, 302).  Wonder if it's supported at all by libevent HTTP package, if so, how do I enable it.

Thanks in advance.

```
void http_request_done(struct evhttp_request *req, void *arg){
    printf("http_request_done\n");
}

int http_req(char *uri, int i) {
    struct evhttp_connection *conn = evhttp_connection_base_new(base, NULL, host, port);
    struct evhttp_request *req = evhttp_request_new(http_request_done, base);
    req->cb_arg = (void*) i;
    evhttp_add_header(req->output_headers, "Host", "localhost");
    evhttp_add_header(req->output_headers, "Connection", "KeepAlive");
    evhttp_make_request(conn, req, EVHTTP_REQ_GET, uri);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ended up doing it manually in  http_request_done() function:

```
void http_request_done(struct evhttp_request *req, void *arg){
    const char *url = evhttp_find_header(evhttp_request_get_input_headers(req), "Location");
    if (url) {
        quickHttpRequest(id, (char*) url);
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```